# xsl group by an external value

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to group a few nodes in my xml by a value outside of those nodes. Nodes I'm trying to group link to outside objects, which are keeping some values.
Here is an example of an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="testgr.xsl"?>
<root>
    <data>
        <host ip="10.0.0.1">
            <soft>
                <name>service1</name>
                <vulners>
                    <vulner id="1"/>
                    <vulner id="2"/>
                    <vulner id="3"/>
                </vulners>
            </soft>
            <soft>
                <name>service2</name>
                <vulners>
                    <vulner id="1"/>
                    <vulner id="2"/>
                    <vulner id="4"/>
                </vulners>
            </soft>
        </host>
        <host ip="10.0.0.2">
            <soft>
                <name>service1</name>
                <vulners>
                    <vulner id="1"/>
                    <vulner id="2"/>
                    <vulner id="3"/>
                </vulners>
            </soft>
            <soft>
                <name>service3</name>
                <vulners>
                    <vulner id="5"/>
                    <vulner id="6"/>
                    <vulner id="7"/>
                </vulners>
            </soft>
        </host>
    </data>
    <vulners>
        <vulner id="1">
            <name>vuln1</name>
            <how_to_fix>update x1</how_to_fix>
        </vulner>
        <vulner id="2">
            <name>vuln2</name>
            <how_to_fix>update x1</how_to_fix>
        </vulner>
        <vulner id="3">
            <name>vuln3</name>
            <how_to_fix>update x2</how_to_fix>
        </vulner>
        <vulner id="4">
            <name>vuln4</name>
            <how_to_fix>update x3</how_to_fix>
        </vulner>
        <vulner id="5">
            <name>vuln5</name>
            <how_to_fix>update x4</how_to_fix>
        </vulner>
        <vulner id="6">
            <name>vuln6</name>
            <how_to_fix>update x4</how_to_fix>
        </vulner>
        <vulner id="7">
            <name>vuln7</name>
            <how_to_fix>update x4</how_to_fix>
        </vulner>
    </vulners>
</root>
```

As you can see, each /root/data/host/soft/vulners node contains some vulner/@id objects, which is a link to /root/vulners/vulner[@id]
I would like to group by /root/vulners/vulner[@id]/how_to_fix value
So the desired result is:

```
<html>
   <HEAD>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <TITLE></TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>№</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>fix</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="3">10.0.0.1,
               service: service1
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>multiple vulns</td>
            <td>update x1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>vuln3</td>
            <td>update x2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="3">10.0.0.1,
               service: service2
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>multiple vulns</td>
            <td>update x1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>vuln4</td>
            <td>update x3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="3">10.0.0.2,
               service: service1
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>multiple vulns</td>
            <td>update x1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>vuln3</td>
            <td>update x2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="3">10.0.0.2,
               service: service3
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>multiple vulns</td>
            <td>update x4</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

I tried the following, but I'm not getting it right. Could someone help, please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <HEAD>
                <TITLE></TITLE>
            </HEAD>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>№</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>fix</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/data/host"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="root/data/host">
        <xsl:variable name="myhost" select="." />
        <xsl:for-each select="soft">
            <xsl:variable name="myservice" select="." />
            <xsl:if test="./vulners/vulner">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan='3'>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$myhost/@ip"/>,
                        service: <xsl:value-of select="$myservice/name"/>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="vulners/vulner" group-by="//root/vulners/vulner[@id=./@id]/how_to_fix">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:variable name="myId" select="@id" />
                        <xsl:variable name="myvuln" select="//root/vulners/vulner[@id=$myId]" />
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="$myvuln/name" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="$myvuln/how_to_fix" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why does your XML contain a link to the stylesheet? You cannot make  XSLT 2.0 grouping work in a browser.

Comment: I was trying to use browser at first. It would be nice to make it browser friendly, but it's not mandatory for now. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to do something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="vulner-by-id" match="vulner" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>fix</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data/host/soft[vulners/vulner]"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="soft">
    <tr>
        <th colspan='3'>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@ip"/>
            <xsl:text>, service: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="key('vulner-by-id', vulners/vulner/@id)" group-by="how_to_fix">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/name" separator=", " />
            </td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="how_to_fix" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result (rendered):**

[image]